# How can I update nvm 10.19 to nvm 14.16

Tags: node.js, nvm

I tried the command `nvm install 14.16.0`. thinking it will update the old version `10.19` to `14.16.0`. when I entered `node -v` on my terminal I noticed my window was still running `10.19`.

Comment: is this about nvm version or node version?

Answer (score -2):

To use a new node version using nvm, we first need to install node:

```
nvm install 14.16.0
```

and then we need to tell nvm to use the new node (missing step)

```
nvm use 14.16.0
```

More details on nvm's webpage:
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#intro